# How to create a qt application for all unix versions?

Tags: qt, build, static, qt5

I have been able create an application that depends on webkit and scripts in Qt5.2.1.But i was able to create a  deb package for 14.04 version Ubuntu .But how can i make it as stand alone application .I have seen static and dynamic build .I tried static build but I don't kon w how to include webkit for static build.Also is it possible with shared library approach for creating a standalone application.Please help me out here..

Comment: This is almost always a lost case, since 1. It's unsupportable. 2. It doesn't leverage any platform-specific tweaks there may be in the platform libraries. You should instead define what distributions you support, and build only for those distributions, providing native packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Deploying a dynamically linked Qt application :**

You should place Qt so files along the release version of your executable. These are `libQtCore.so`, `libQtGui.so` and possibly the ones for other modules that you have used. These so files are in your installed Qt directory in lib folder or in the directory `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`. If you are using plugins you should place their so files in a folder named `plugins` beside your binary. In case of using icons and images you should ship their so files like `libqico.so` and `libqsvg.so` in a folder named `imageformats`.

**Gathering required shared libraries :**

If you want your application to run independently on a bare installed Linux, you should gather all dependent shared libraries and put them in your application directory. You can simply do it by a shell script named [cpld](http://h3manth.com/content/copying-shared-library-dependencies). You can easily copy all dependencies to a folder.

It's worthy to note that you can put this in your .pro file to cause the dynamic linker to look in the same directory as your Qt application at runtime in Linux :

```
unix:{
    # suppress the default RPATH if you wish
    QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH=
    # add your own with quoting gyrations to make sure $ORIGIN gets to the command line unexpanded
    QMAKE_LFLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath,\'\$$ORIGIN\'"
}
```

Comment: I have added the shared library dependencies in a folder name dependency and added this as  QMAKE_LFLAGS_RPATH=dependecy/ in .pro file in the current working directory say app-1.0 .But after generating the executable file and checking it still points to the system path like usr/lib  ro usr/inc how can i point it from current working directory app-1.0