# Deploying Qt application, on Mac OSX and Linux, what libraries do I need to include in package?

Tags: linux, macos, qt, deployment, shared-libraries

I am trying to package / deploy a Qt app, in Linux and mac. (Qt 4.8).  I have to use shared libraries due to licensing type.

in Linux, following Qt [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-x11.html#application-dependencies), I ran `ldd myprogram` and got an output like

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb76fa000)
libOneOfMyLibs.so.1 => /usr/local/lib/libOneOfMyLibs.so.1 (0xb76d7000)
libQtGui.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4 (0xb5440000)
libQtCore.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4 (0xb501a000)
.......
libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0xb4316000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb4fba000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb4f9c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb4df0000)
libcups.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcups.so.2 (0xb4d91000)
libsqlite3.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0xb4cbb000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb4cb6000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb4c99000)
libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xb4c56000)
libaudio.so.2 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libaudio.so.2 (0xb4c3c000)
libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xb4b41000)
libpng12.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0xb4b14000)
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0xb4a67000)
libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xb4a16000)
.....
```

very many dependencies, only some of them are Qt libs . But then they say, that since it cannot be certain what the installed program will be running, I should package all the library dependencies.

There are sooo many !!! I definitely require some of them like sqlite3. I also read that libfreetype and libfontconfig are required since they may be different on the new system.

How can I know which libs are required though ? Should I package all of them ?

The mac [directions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html) only show that I must add the Qt libraries. Even though, listing dependencies on mac, I get

```
myprogram.app/Contents/MacOS/myprogram:
    libOneOfMyLibs.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.6.0)
    /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.8.0)
    QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.6)
    QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (compatibility version 4.8.0, current version 4.8.6)
    ....
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 832.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 125.2.11)
```

on mac - do I need to add libstdc++.6.dylib and the rest ?

From Qt [documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/developing-on-mac.html):

> "The application bundle contains the application executable as well as
>   dependencies such as the Qt libraries, plugins, translations and other
>   resources you may need. Third party libraries like Qt are normally not
>   installed system-wide; each application provides its own copy."

To summarize my question:

If I do not want to make any assumptions about the system I want to deploy for, do I need to add all the system library dependencies, or only the Qt libraries, or... which are the libraries that I must add to my package ?

Comment: You can see this post for Linux deployment : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967340/how-to-create-a-qt-application-for-all-unix-versions/25967872#25967872

Comment: Thank you - it still does not say what should be or shouldn't, required dependent library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All libs that your program links to are needed somehow.  That's the reason many Linuxes have their own packaging system: there are libs residing on every system of that distribution - so you wouldn't have to package those - and they know how to manage dependencies - so you only provide a list of deps and your application.

Regarding Linux this means: to create a package for a specific distribution, use the distribution's packaging system.  (Most of them help a great deal so you do not have to fiddle around with what's needed and what's not.)

Packaging for "any Linux" would mean:

- include all dependencies
- write an installer that MUST not overwrite existing files

The easiest way to provide a package for "all" distributions: distribute source using a well-known build system (like Autotools or CMake), tell the user what external libraries are used in your code, so he/she can install those before trying to build your application.

I'm sorry, I don't know about MacOS's requirements.  My guess is: there is some packaging system you can simply use.

Comment: I still don't know if I should add ALL libs that ldd lists - all these posts and tutorials seem to ignore any libs except for the Qt libs. For example, libgcc - a very basic build library that I am sure everybody who has to do this lists as a dependency - can I be sure that any system will have it, and the right version ?

Comment: May I stress this again (regarding linux): use the packaging system of the distribution you want to deploy the application on.  All sophisticated distros have How-To's to use their packaging, although f.e. on gentoo it's a bit hard to get into.
Also this post gives all the hints necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967340/how-to-create-a-qt-application-for-all-unix-versions/25967872#25967872 to deploy on a bare linux-from-scratch.

Comment: It seems that I was overthinking it, and should really not include any dependencies listed except any that I do not expect a system to have, or may have a wrong version (like sqlite3)